# How to maximize browser (IE) with Watir using Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

I am new in `Watir` as well as Ruby. I have written an automated test for google search using `Watir` and executed it successfully (my file name is `"googlesearch.rb"`). But the browser (`IE`) was opened as small window. How to maximize the browser using Watir?

My watir test script is as below:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto("www.google.com")
browser.text_field(:id, "gbqfq").set("Ripon Al Wasim")
browser.button(:name, "btnG").click
browser.link(:text, "User Ripon Al Wasim - Stack Overflow").click
```

I executed the test script by using the command: `ruby googlesearch.rb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **watir-webdriver**: You just need to use the method [`#maximize`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Window#maximize-instance_method).

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto("www.google.com")
browser.window.maximize
# ... rest code here goes
```

Or, if you are using only **watir** gem to work with [`IE` browser only on Windows](http://watir.com/examples/). Then you could write it as using [`maximize`](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/w/watir-classic-4.0.1/Watir/Browser.html#method-i-maximize).

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto("www.google.com")
browser.maximize
# ... rest code here goes
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. An error is shown:  googlesearch.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `maximize' for #<Watir::Window:0x2b39f08> (NoMethodError)

Comment: watir (5.0.0 x86-mingw32)
watir-classic (4.0.1)

Comment: When can I use browser.window.maximize ?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim You have to use another gem `watir-webdriver` then... See my answer. I gave all the links.